# Greying out text box based on button clicked

Tags: jquery, html

What I'm looking to do is based when you select the button for "No Date" it will grey out my to and from text boxes that appear below it.

```
     <td width="33%" valign="top">
   <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td width="40%">
                Search by
            </td>
            <td width="60%">
            <input type="radio" id="frm_date_type1" name="frm_date_type" value="" checked="checked" />&nbsp;No Date
            <input type="radio" id="frm_date_type2" name="frm_date_type" value="admit"/>&nbsp;Admit
            <input type="radio" id="frm_date_type3" name="frm_date_type" value="discharge"/>&nbsp;Discharge                                  
            <input type="radio" id="frm_date_type4" name="frm_date_type" value="audit" />&nbsp;Audit
            <input type="radio" id="frm_date_type5" name="frm_date_type" value="import" />&nbsp;Import

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="40%">
                Date From
            </td>
           <td width="60%">

              <input type="text"  class="date" id="from" name="from"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="40%">
                Date To
            </td>
            <td width="60%">
               <input type="text"  class="date" id="to" name="to" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
```

Comment: Where is your javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("[name=frm_date_type]").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("id") === "frm_date_type1"){
        $("#to, #from").attr("disabled", true);        
    }
    else{
        $("#to, #from").removeAttr("disabled");       
    }
}).filter(':checked').click();
```

Like that?

[Now with Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XiozZe/nH9zx/5/)

Comment: If you chain a `.filter(':checked').click()` the settings will be applied onready

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you.

```
 $('#frm_date_type1').click(function() {
   $('#from').attr('disable');
   $('#to').attr('disable');
 });
```